# Runnables and Activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have currently the following problem:

I got a server that provides and API via Google Protobuf. A Program (in this case an Android App) can request informations. I have an Activity in Android that will request Informations in the Background via a `Runnable`, which will then process the network request and dispatch to a function on the mainthread to update the UI with the new informations. Therefore I give the runnable a `final interface` with the function to dispatch which is implemented by the `Activity`. Now as the network stuff happens in the background and the UI should not block (e.g. with a Loading Spinner) I dont know what happens when the user switches to another Activity while the `Runnable` is still active. Will it still dispatch properly even if there is another `Activity` active? What is good design practice to solve this.

Of course I thought about adding a variable to the `Runnable` to mark it as `dont dispatch`, but there still could be race conditions (it gets dispatched while the user hits the back button, which would already have the dispatched function in the queue for the mainthread before marking the `Runnable` as aborted).

If you need any additional informations, please ask, I am happy to provide them.

Comment: see [bound services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services)

Comment: Hey, thank you, but I do not intent to use a service. Also the connection wont be permament, only when requesting infos. And these infos only will be requested when the GUI is visible.